# Finding an instance of a word or phrase in a string

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program where the user inputs a string and the user can then select from a menu to do things such as display the number of words in the string or number of spaces in the string. I have all functions working except for the one where I need to be able to find the number of instances of a specific word or phrase. Whenever I enter a word or phrase it says there are 0 occurrences. This is my entire code but again I just need help with my FindText function. Bare in mind I'm a beginner programmer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string user_text = " ";
string find_text = " ";
string replaced = " ";
char print_menu(char);
int GetNumOfNonWSCharacters(string);
int GetNumOfWords(string);
int FindText(string, string);
string ReplaceExclamation(string);
string ShortenSpace(string);
int main()
{

    char choice = ' ';

    cout << "Enter a sample text: ";
    getline(cin, user_text);

    choice = print_menu(choice);
    while (!(choice == 'q'))
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 'c': //number of non-whitespace characters
            int not_space;
            not_space = GetNumOfNonWSCharacters(user_text);
            cout << "Number of non white space charactesr: " << not_space << endl;
            choice = print_menu(choice);
            break;
        case 'w': //number of words
            int words;
            words = GetNumOfWords(user_text);
            cout << "Number of words: " << words << endl;
            choice = print_menu(choice);
            break;
        case 'f': //find text
            int occurences;
            cout << "Enter a word or phrase to be found: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, find_text);
            occurences = FindText(find_text, user_text);
            cout << find_text << " instances: " << occurences << endl;
            choice = print_menu(choice);
            break;
        case 'r': //replace all !'s
            replaced = ReplaceExclamation(user_text);
            cout << replaced << endl;
            choice = print_menu(choice);

            break;
        case 's': //shorten spaces
            replaced = ShortenSpace(user_text);
            cout << replaced << endl;
            choice == print_menu(choice);

            break;
        case 'q': //quit
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid choice please try again";
            choice = print_menu(choice);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
char print_menu(char choice)
{
    cout << "MENU" << endl;
    cout << "   c - Number of non - whitespace characters" << endl;
    cout << "   w - Number of words" << endl;
    cout << "   f - Find text" << endl;
    cout << "   r - Replace all !'s" << endl;
    cout << "   s - Shorten spaces" << endl;
    cout << "   q - Quit" << endl;
    cout << "   Choose an option ";

    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}
int GetNumOfNonWSCharacters(string text)
{
    int spaces = 0;
    int not_spaces = text.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isspace(text.at(i)) != false)
        {
            spaces += 1;
        }
    }
    not_spaces = not_spaces - spaces;
    return not_spaces;
}
int GetNumOfWords(string text)
{
    int words = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (text.at(i) == ' ')
        {
            words++;
        }
    }
    return words + 1;
}
int FindText(string find, string text)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (text.find(find) == true)
        {
            count++;
        }

    }
    return count;
}
string ReplaceExclamation(string text)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (text.at(i) == '!')
        {
            text.at(i) = '.';
        }
    }
    return text;
}
string ShortenSpace(string text)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (text.at(i) == ' ' && text.at(i + 1) == ' ')
        {
            text.erase(text.begin() + i);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think you should reduce your code snippet to the [absolute necessary minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it more attractive for others here to read, understand and help you.

Comment: Unrelated: You have a typo in `case 's'`: `choice == print_menu(choice);` -> `choice = print_menu(choice);`

Comment: Tactical note: It's best to `cin.ignore();` after the operation that leaves something you want ignored rather than before a subsequent operation. After the operation usually happens once and before the next sometimes had many places. Why duplicate code? Plus keeping related code close together makes it harder to screw up. For example, you may forget to place an `ignore` or you may place an ignore where you don't always have something that needs ignoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `string::find()` returns `size_type` and not `bool`
- Use an overload of `find()` that allows you to specify the starting position.

  ```
      size_type find( const basic_string& str, size_type pos = 0 )
  ```
- Once the string is found, add its length to the starting position and use `find` again to find the next occurrence.

You can modify your function thus:

```
int FindText(string find, string text)
{
    int count = 0;
    string::size_type start = 0;
    while ((start = text.find(find, start)) != string::npos) {
        ++count;
        start += find.length(); 
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: It's still not running how I need it to. If I for example type in the string "hello world, hello world" and then call the FindText function and ask for the occurrences of the world "hello", it says there is only one occurrence.

Comment: @AlexCPSC: There was a copy/paste mistake in the code. Updated it. It will work now. I have tested it. Check out this link. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7064f306d3f1b613